# Create .xcappdata from ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I know how to download files *.xcappdata from iOS device and use it during test and running simulation.

There is a similar feature for downloading data from iOS simulator?

Now I manually  copy/restore application folder inside the simulator but using the xCode functionality can be very handy.

thanks.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?